# jquery form validation allow only standard USA numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form-validator

I found this plugin good so far [Jquery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/) as so far it has fulfilled all my requirements but i am stuck to set validation for the users to enter only **USA mobile number format** something like this **1-(XXX)-XXX-XXXX** . It should allow only this number to enter else it should not accept and should show form validation error.

I have researched but unable to find any tutorial or demo code which is showing how to achieve this particular thing and hence i had to put this question.

Can someone guide me or show me some code if possible how to achieve this using **data-*** attributes in html tags (i.e. `<input data-validation="creditcard" data-validation-allowing="visa, mastercard, amex">`) or any other way with the help of utilizing this plugin..

I am trying to utilize this [Configuration Callbacks](http://www.formvalidator.net/#configuration_callbacks) but i am bit confused how to utilize this as i have multiple forms and i have only put this code in my **common.js** file for all the forms which works well using for all the forms.

```
$.validate({
             modules : 'security, file'
        });
```

So i want something like common **data-*** attribute (*if its available*)   which can work in a parcular html form which can be feasible for me as i do not need to type different code based on different form like this `$.validate({form : '#LoginForm'});` as above common method will be feasible for me ..

Can someone help me to achieve this thing please ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: oh really .. i was kidding .. i have come up with the solution .. please read my answer .. your link helped me and i sorted out my question with ease. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I have sorted out this thing with ease thanks to **@mplungjan** who provided me a link and shown me a **way** how to accomplish this.

I simply went here to the library [Default validation custom](http://www.formvalidator.net/#default-validators_custom) and I see they actually are providing the facility to make **regex validation** on the go ..

I searched regex to check US mobile numbers [Phone Number Regex US](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/phone-number-nanp/index.html)

And then after finding a regex to work with, I used this HTML code,

```
<input name="user_mobile_no" class="form-control error" placeholder="Mobile No." 
data-validation="required custom" 
data-validation-error-msg-required="Please Enter Mobile Number" 
data-validation-regexp="\D*([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)(\d{4})\D*" 
data-validation-error-msg-custom="Invalid Mobile Number (i.e. +1 XXX-XXX-XXXX)" 
maxlength="50" id="user-mobile-no" value="+1 215-555-1212" 
style="border-color: rgb(185, 74, 72);" type="text">
```

And **voila**, its working.

Notice these lines I have put above, `data-validation="required custom"`  **custom** is required to put there to make custom validation.

Then after I put

```
data-validation-regexp="\D*([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)(\d{4})\D*"
```

which checks valid phone numbers and last but not the least, i have put two different validation error messages to show to the users for **required** `data-validation-error-msg-required="Please Enter Mobile Number"`  and **invalid number** `data-validation-error-msg-custom="Invalid Mobile Number (i.e. +1 XXX-XXX-XXXX)"` .

Thanks guys for support. I hope it helps someone who needs to deal with similar thing. Really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*
It works for these number formats:
1-234-567-8901
1-234-567-8901 x1234
1-234-567-8901 ext1234
1 (234) 567-8901
1.234.567.8901
1/234/567/8901
12345678901
1-234-567-8901 ext. 1234
(+351) 282 433 5050
*/

jQuery.validator.addMethod("usPhoneFormat", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\(*\+*[1-9]{0,3}\)*-*[1-9]{0,3}[-. /]*\(*[2-9]\d{2}\)*[-. /]*\d{3}[-. /]*\d{4} *e*x*t*\.* *\d{0,4}$/.test(value);
}, "Enter a valid phone number.");


$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#sampleForm").validate({
    rules: {
      phoneNumberRegEx: {
        usPhoneFormat: true,
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      alert("submitted.");
    }
  });
  $(".phone").mask("0-000-000-0000", {placeholder: "_-___-___-____"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<form id="sampleForm" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="phoneNumberRegEx">Phone: </label>
        <input type="text" id="phoneNumberRegEx" name="phoneNumberRegEx" class="phone" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I guess we do not require any third party library if the same library works for us which i mentioned in question itself dear. What are your thoughts on it.

Comment: You are using the jquery validator library. If you want, remove the mask library.

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna have advanced validation with specific series codes, u can try to use data from this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialcodes